# Using std::error_code - shall I call .clear() after a possible error case?

Tags: c++, error-handling

I have a class, with `static std::error_code s_ec{}` member in it, which I use in every method of this class. Is it safe to use it like this? Or shall I call `s_er.clear()` after every `s_er` use?
For example, piece of a method

```
        wstring addFoldName{L""};
        if (copyWithFolder)
        {
            std::filesystem::directory_entry temp(from, s_er);
            if (s_er)
            {
                lasterr = GetLastError();
                YiffySpyLog::fillYiffySpy((wstring)funcDescForLog + L"[Copy] Copy to <" + to.wstring() + L"> - failed, couldn't retrieve directory info, GetLastError()=" + std::to_wstring(lasterr) + L", std::error_code.message()=" + stringToWstring(s_er.message(), (wstring)funcDescForLog + L"[Copy] "), 0b100);
                return false;
            }
            if (temp.is_directory())
                addFoldName = (wstring)FurSpace::s_pthDiv + from.filename().wstring();
        }
        if (!fromIsParent) // if from is not parent - performing usual copying
            std::filesystem::copy(from, (wstring)to.wstring() + addFoldName, copyOptions, s_er);
        if (s_er)
        {
            lasterr = GetLastError();
            YiffySpyLog::fillYiffySpy((wstring)funcDescForLog + L"[Copy] Copy to <" + to.wstring() + L"> - failed, couldn't copy, GetLastError()=" + std::to_wstring(lasterr) + L", std::error_code.message()=" + stringToWstring(s_er.message(), (wstring)funcDescForLog + L"[Copy] "), 0b100);
            return false;
        }
```

Shall I use `s_er.clear()` before calling another method inside this class, that shares `s_er` between all it's methods, or it resets on it's own after every use?

Another example

```
    // sniffs for all the folders and files inside a given folder, if recursive is true - sniffs also in folders inside folders
    bool EasyFilesystem::searchForFileFolder(vector<std::filesystem::directory_entry>& arrayToFillWithInfo, const std::filesystem::path& directoryToSearchIn, bool recursive, const wstring& funcDescForLog)
    {
        bool searchState{ true };
        if (!recursive)
        {
            for (auto& dir : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(directoryToSearchIn, std::filesystem::directory_options::skip_permission_denied | std::filesystem::directory_options::follow_directory_symlink, s_er))
            {
                if (s_er && searchState)
                {
                    lasterr = GetLastError();
                    YiffySpyLog::fillYiffySpy((wstring)funcDescForLog + L"[FindFile] File search failed! Something went wrong while iterating through <" + directoryToSearchIn.wstring() + L">. GetLastError()=" + std::to_wstring(lasterr) + L", std::error_code.message()=" + stringToWstring(s_er.message(), (wstring)funcDescForLog + L"[FindFile] "), 0b100);
                    searchState = false;
                }
                arrayToFillWithInfo.push_back(dir);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (auto& dir : std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(directoryToSearchIn, std::filesystem::directory_options::skip_permission_denied | std::filesystem::directory_options::follow_directory_symlink, s_er))
            {
                if (s_er && searchState)
                {
                    lasterr = GetLastError();
                    YiffySpyLog::fillYiffySpy((wstring)funcDescForLog + L"[FindFile] File search failed! Something went wrong while recursively iterating through <" + directoryToSearchIn.wstring() + L">. GetLastError()=" + std::to_wstring(lasterr) + L", std::error_code.message()=" + stringToWstring(s_er.message(), (wstring)funcDescForLog + L"[FindFile] "), 0b100);
                    searchState = false;
                }
                arrayToFillWithInfo.push_back(dir);
            }
        }
        return searchState;
    }
```

As you may see, `s_er` is used here again. If I catch an error in previous piece of code, will I run into a problem in the latest method shown? As I think, `std::filesystem::directory_entry temp(from, s_er);` will reset the `s_er` state, so no matter if I catched an error before, `s_er` state shall be reset on any newer call. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I read more info about it, which I just didn't see before...
And I think I was right, it clears itself on its own.
As written here:

> Exceptions
>
> The overload that does not take a `std::error_code&` parameter throws
> `filesystem::filesystem_error` on underlying OS API errors, constructed
> with `p` as the first path argument and the OS error code as the error
> code argument. The overload taking a `std::error_code&` parameter sets
> it to the OS API error code if an OS API call fails, **and executes
> `ec.clear()` if no errors occur**. Any overload not marked `noexcept` may
> throw std::bad_alloc if memory allocation fails.

Considering `std::filesystem::directory_entry` does so - I think every other function also does that.

So I think it is safe to use `std::error_code` the way I use it in my classes, sharing its static member instead of creating a new `std::error_code` variable in every method.